# How can I paste 100000 without it being shortened to 1e+05?

Tags: r, r-faq

**Question**: How can I use `paste` without `100000` becoming `1e+05`?

Sorry in advance if this question seems frivolous (but it has resulted in a bug in my code).  I use R to call an external script, so when I say e.g. `paste("abc",100000)` I want it to output `"abc 100000"` and not `"abc 1e+05"`.

Here's an example of what it looks like on my screen:

```
> paste("abc",100000)
[1] "abc 1e+05"
> paste("abc",100001)
[1] "abc 100001"
```

This results in the bizarre behaviour that my script works for the input "100001" but not "100000".

I realise I could create a script to convert numbers to strings however I like, but I feel I shouldn't do this if there is an internal way to do the same thing (I suspect there is some "method" I'm missing).

[If it helps, I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS ("precise"), running R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22) in a terminal.]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See `?options`, particularly `scipen`:

```
R> paste("abc", 100000)
[1] "abc 1e+05"
R> options("scipen"=10)    # set high penalty for scientific display
R> paste("abc", 100000)
[1] "abc 100000"
R>
```

Alternatively, control formatting tightly the old-school way via `sprintf()`:

```
R> sprintf("%s %6d", "abc", 100000)
[1] "abc 100000"
R>
```

Comment: Or just put the "100000" in quotes too...

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively, you can use integers which don't get printed in scientific notation. You can specify that your number is an integer by putting an "L" behind it, or doing as.integer.

```
> paste("abc",100000L)
[1] "abc 100000"
> paste("abc",as.integer(1000000000))
[1] "abc 1000000000"
```

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively `format` may be simpler than `sprintf` especially when you want to change how decimals are displayed:

```
> paste("abc",format(100000, scientific = FALSE))
[1] "abc 100000"
> paste("abc",format(0.1234567, scientific = FALSE, digits = 4))
[1] "abc 0.1235"
```